# cloud functions return error when using local parse database: "fail Error: The server returned an invalid response."

Tags: back4app

using parse dashboard in local system, implemented cloud functions and getting an error when call cloud function

main.js:

Parse.Cloud.define('cloudFunctions', function (req, res) {

const query = new Parse.Query("Test");

```
if (req.params.Name) {

    query.equalTo('Name', req.params.Name);

}

query.find()

    .then((results) => {

        var testArray = new Array();

        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            testArray[i] = {

                id: results[i].id,

                Name: results[i].get("Name"),

                Description: results[i].get("Description")

            };

        }

        var obj={

            result:testArray

        }

        res.success(obj);

    }, (error) => {

        res.success("Save failed! " + error);

    });
```

});

client side:

var gettestparams = {

```
  Name: ""
```

}

Parse.Cloud.run('cloudFunctions', gettestparams).then(function (callback) {

```
    console.log("get test call", callback);
```

}).catch((error) => {

```
console.log("fail", error);
```

});

Comment: What is the parse version that you are using?

Comment: I have tried these parse versions 3.1.1 and 3.7.0

Comment: For Parse Server versions >3, you don't have the res object anymore. You need to use the async style. See an example here:https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions